# F# P/Invoke Marshaling Recursive Structures

Tags: f#, pinvoke, recursive-datastructures

None of the examples I have seen thus far appear to address the problem of marshaling a structure containing a union of structures that contain recursive references. I am attempting to write a marshaler for a structure which contains these and have so far failed.

For example:

```
typedef enum {
    My_StructA = 0x7878,
    My_StructB
} MyStructTag;

 typedef struct _MyStruct MyStruct;  

 struct _MyStruct {  
     MyStructTag discriminator;  
     union {  
        struct {  
            int a;  
            int b;  
        } StructA;  

        struct {  
            int c;  
            MyStruct* d;  
        } StructB;
    } MyUnion;  
};
```

I attempted to define the structures as follows:

```
type MyStructTag =
    | My_StructA = 0x7878
    | My_StructB = 0x7879

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type StructA =
    val mutable a : int
    val mutable b : int

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type StructB =
    val mutable c : int
    val mutable d : MyStruct

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type MyStruct =
    [<FieldOffset(0)>] val discriminator : MyStructTag
    [<FieldOffset(4)>] val structA : StructA
    [<FieldOffset(4)>] val structB : StructB
```

Note that the reason I bothered to define MyStruct explicitly is to allow myself to make use of Marshal.OffsetOf() and Marshal.SizeOf() when writing the custom marshaler for this structure. From what I have seen, writing a custom marshaler is the only way to handle unions. If I am wrong about that, references would be greatly appreciated!

The error I receive when writing the above code is:

```
error FS0039: The type 'MyStruct' is not defined
```

I assume this is because only discriminated union types can be defined recursively. However, I am not aware of any other way to represent these structures in F#.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two problems.  First of all, any mutually recursive types (whether discriminated unions, classes, or structs) need to be defined using

```
type A = ... 
and B = ...
```

rather than

```
type A = ... 
type B = ...
```

(and note that attributes can come before or after the word `type`, but only after the word `and`...).  However, if you try this, you'll see that you just get a different error, because structs can't be directly recursive as fields of each other.  If struct A had a field which was a struct B and struct B had a field which was a struct A (and either of them had any other fields), then the size would be infinite.  Note that this is true of your C code as well - `StructB` contains a *pointer* to a `MyStruct`, not a `MyStruct` itself.  In .NET, you can use an `IntPtr` for this - in F# you can use the `nativeint` alias or `nativeptr<MyStruct>`.  Try this:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type MyStructTag =
| My_StructA = 0x7878
| My_StructB = 0x7879

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type StructA =
  val mutable a : int
  val mutable b : int

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type StructB =
  val mutable c : int
  val mutable d : nativeptr<MyStruct>

and [<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]MyStruct =
    [<FieldOffset(0)>] val discriminator : MyStructTag
    [<FieldOffset(4)>] val structA : StructA
    [<FieldOffset(4)>] val structB : StructB
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did it. One question - I have never seen the nativeptr<|insert unmanaged type here|> construct. MSDN doesn't have a good explanation and google codesearch did not yield any enlightening snippets.

Comment: @arachnid - `nativeptr<'t>` is an F#-specific type for dealing with pointers.  In reality, it is just an alias for `System.IntPtr`, but the `NativeInterop.NativePtr` module provides several useful functions for interacting with these pointers in a strongly-typed way.